# Set default value for proceduce in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want write proceduce have parameter which have default value if no value pass to it, something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE client_logging_system.Proc_client_Get(IN in_clientID INT DEFAULT 1)
  COMMENT '
-- Proc for get user
-- Parameter:
-- in_clientID: ID of client
'
BEGIN
  SELECT c.ID, c.Name, c.BrokerID, c.LoginID, c.Password, c.`GroupID`, c.Quanity, c.ApiKey, c.ToTp FROM `client` c
  WHERE c.ID = in_clientID;
END
```

Any one have suggestion about this problem?

Comment: This has been an open feature request of MySQL stored procedures since 2005: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975. I don't think you should expect it to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is defined then you **MUST** provide a value for it. You cannot skip the value.

If you do not want to specify the value and apply some "default" onу then you'd do this in the code:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE client_logging_system.Proc_client_Get(IN in_clientID INT)
BEGIN
SET in_clientID = COALESCE(in_clientID, 1);  -- if NULL is provided then set to default value 1
...
```

Accordingly you use `CALL client_logging_system.Proc_client_Get(123)` for definite parameter value and `CALL client_logging_system.Proc_client_Get(NULL)` for to apply default value.